# My CORS request started to fail after a security update to Apache2. I can't figure out why.

Tags: php, ajax, apache, cross-domain, cors

Everything was working until yesterday, and it has been working for months. After an apache security update that mentioned XSS atacks preventions, it stopped working though.

I have spent hours on this, can't figure out what's wrong. As you can see from the headers below, Chrome requests preflight info, apache responds and them chrome says:

**XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://neo.octomobi.com/plupload/upload_gallery.php. Origin http://www.octomobi.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.**

Any ideas? What is wrong with apache's answer to the preflight??

```
Request URL:http://neo.xxx.com/xxxx/xxxx (domain hidden by me for security)
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:200 OK
```

**Request Headers**

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Access-Control-Request-Headers:origin, content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
Host:neo.xxxx.com
Origin:http://www.xxxx.com (hidden by me)
Proxy-Connection:keep-alive
Referer:http://www.xxxx.com/xxx/xxxx (hidden by me)
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11
```

**Response Headers**

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Allow:GET,HEAD,POST,OPTIONS
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:0
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Mon, 12 Nov 2012 11:47:17 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Proxy-Connection:Keep-Alive
Server:Apache/2.2.20 (Ubuntu)
Via:1.1 FTHW937X
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.3.6-13ubuntu3.9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error, I got it to work.

What I understand from it is that for some reason Apache is only sending Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * in the preflight request, but not in the actual request. It needs to be present in both the preflight and the actual request or else the CORS fails.

And that's happening even though I have Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * in the Apache config files and in htaccess (and by the way it was working until I applied this Apache patch).

So the solution I found was to explicitly put header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); in the PHP return. It's not ideal because I had to modify a lot of files to include it, I would rather have figured out why it stopped working in the first place. But at least it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); ?>
```

you can just put Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin * setting on apache conf or htaccess file it just work Or do the following

```
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
</ifModule>
```

Comment: I have tried that but it won't work. Also, if you look at apache's response header, it already contains Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * so that's not the problem. There must be something else missing in the response header that is making the connection get rejected.